# Can PySNMP find the MIB name for an OID?

Tags: python, pysnmp, mib

What I need to do is write a function that finds the MIB name for a given OID. 
E.g when I give '1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6' as an argument, it should return 'ifHCInOctets'. I've been searching the PySNMP documentation and Stack Overflow but didn't find anything so: Is this something that's possible with PySNMP, or do I have to write a parser for the MIB files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with pysnmp, you do not need to create a MIB parser. ;-)

If you follow [this example](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/smi/manager/browsing-mib-tree.html#snmp-mib-browser), specifically these pieces:

```
from pysnmp.smi import builder, view, compiler

mibBuilder = builder.MibBuilder()
compiler.addMibCompiler(mibBuilder, sources=['/usr/share/snmp/mibs'])
mibBuilder.loadModules('IF-MIB', ...)
mibView = view.MibViewController(mibBuilder)

oid, label, suffix = mibView.getNodeName((1,3,6,1,2,1,31,1,1,1,6))
```

The `label` variable should return `ifHCInOctets`. One caveat here is that you need to load the MIB that defines the OID before you could look it up. The unresolved tail of the OID might appear in `suffix`.

Another approach could be to use pysmi's [mibdump](http://snmplabs.com/pysmi/mibdump.html) tool (or the underlying [pysmi](http://snmplabs.com/pysmi/library-reference.html) library) to turn ASN.1 MIBs into JSON for further processing by your application.

BTW, the same tool can build a JSON [index](http://snmplabs.com/pysmi/mibdump.html#building-mib-indices) which would look like [this](http://mibs.snmplabs.com/json/index.json). You could use it to map your OID onto the MIB module where it's defined.

Comment: Hello Ilya, I tried your code for a MIB called ORION-BASE-MIB and it gave the following error >>

`
pysnmp.smi.error.MibNotFoundError: ORION-BASE-MIB compilation error(s): missing; missing; missing; no module "SNMPv2-SMI" in symbolTable at MIB ORION-BASE-MIB
`

Could you please help?

Comment: You might be missing `SNMPv2-SMI` (and other dependencies) in the search path (i.e. sources variable).